# Script not logging to file when run from cron, but works fine otherwise

Tags: scripts, cron, rsync

Here's my crontab entry:

```
0 0 * * * /root/scripts/InsyncDAILY.sh
```

Here's the script:

```
rsync -av --delete /mnt/RAID1/Insync/ /media/apeters/10TB/Insync/daily/ &> "/var/log/backups/INSYNC_DAILY_$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%p).log"
```

The log file is created properly so I know it is running at the right time, but it's empty. When I run the script manually I get a bunch of output from rsync as expected.

I don't appear to get anything in my mail either.

Any suggestions as to how to get the log file to contain the expected output?

Comment: Does the script have a shebang? if not, it will be executed in `/bin/sh` - which doesn't understand the `&>` redirection bashism

Comment: No it did not. I didn't realize that was necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

via steeldriver

> Does the script have a shebang? if not, it will be executed in /bin/sh - which doesn't understand the &> redirection bashism

That does it.